# Sum specific number of columns for each row with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have the dollowing dataframe:

```
   name  code     1   2  3  4  5  6  7 .........155    days
0  Lari  EH214    0   5  2  1  0  0  0           0      3
1  Suzi  FK362    0   0  0  0  2  3  0           0      108
2  Jil   LM121    0   0  4  2  1  0  0           0      5
...
```

I want to sum the column between column 1 to column with the number that appears on "days" , for example,
for row 1, I will **sum 3 days-> 0+5+2**
For row 2 108 days,
for row 3 **5 days->0+4+2+1+0**

How can I do something like this?
Looking for method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vectorized solution filter rows by positions first and get mask by compare `days` in numpy boroadasting, if not match replace `0` in [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and last `sum`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:, 2:-1]

m = df1.columns.astype(int).to_numpy() <= df['days'].to_numpy()[:, None]

df['sum'] = df1.where(m, 0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   name   code  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  155  days  sum
0  Lari  EH214  0  5  2  1  0  0  0    0     3    7
1  Suzi  FK362  0  0  0  0  2  3  0    0   108    5
2   Jil  LM121  0  0  4  2  1  0  0    0     5    7
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use:

```
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.loc[1: r['days']].sum(), axis=1)
```

or, if the column names are strings:

```
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.loc['1': str(r['days'])].sum(), axis=1)
```

output:

```
   name   code  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  155  days  sum
0  Lari  EH214  0  5  2  1  0  0  0    0     3    7
1  Suzi  FK362  0  0  0  0  2  3  0    0   108    5
2   Jil  LM121  0  0  4  2  1  0  0    0     5    7
```